# Multiple administrator connecting to a router - who has precedence? Can they monitor each other's logs?

Tags: cisco-ios

Just getting started in Networking. Came across multiple administrators connecting over Telnet.

Does someone who connected first have precedence over everyone else?
Does a admin connected to VTY line 1 see the logs of VTY 5 if V5 change something V1 configured?

If someone could point to a resource video/article that goes over this topic I'd appreciate. I couldn't find anything useful when googling "multiple administrator connecting to a cisco router" - also I was quickly overwhelmed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each VTY session has the same priority/precedence.  So yes, every session can see logs, make changes, *etc*.

For example, if you have the `terminal monitor` feature enabled, you will see real time logs of any status change made, regardless of which VTY session made it.